# If $F_X, F_Y$ agree for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, Do their distributions $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ agree on $\mathcal{B}$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

Let random variables X and Y be defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Assume their distribution functions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ agree for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. How would I conclude that that their distributions $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ agree on $\mathcal{B}$?

Would the same hold if the assumption was that $F_X$ and $F_Y$ agreed for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What is $\mathcal B?$

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ I assume.

Comment: The cdf defines the distribution hence the answer is yes.

Comment: What do you mean by *"their distributions $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$"*?

Comment: @Xi'an is this also true for the second part of the question. Is it sufficient to define the CDF in the space $\mathbb{Q}$, if we consider events that include points from the space $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 5):

**Observation $1.$** Let $\mathbf P_1, ~\mathbf P_2$ be two probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal F). $ Let $\mathcal P$ be a $\pi$-system such that $$\mathbf P_1(A) =\mathbf P_2(A), ~~~\forall A\in \mathcal P. \tag 1$$ Then $$\mathbf P_1\left(A^\prime\right) =\mathbf P_2\left(A^\prime\right), ~~~\forall A^\prime\in \sigma(\mathcal P) . \tag 2$$

**Proof:** It is easy to check that $\mathcal L:=\{A\in \mathcal F: \mathbf P_1(A) =\mathbf P_2(A)\}$ is a $\lambda$-system. By $(1),~\mathcal P\subset \mathcal L$ whence by Dynkin's theorem, $\sigma(\mathcal P) \subset \mathcal L. $

**Observation $2.$** If $\mathbf P_1, ~\mathbf P_2$ are probability measures on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B) $ such that $$\mathrm F_1(x) = \mathrm F_2(x), ~~\forall x\in \mathbb R, \tag 3$$ then $$\mathbf P_1\equiv \mathbf P_2\tag 4$$ on $\mathcal B. $

**Proof.** Take $\mathcal P:= \{(-\infty,x]: x\in \mathbb R\};$ it is a $\pi$-system. Also $\sigma(\mathcal P) =\mathcal B. $ By Observation $1,  ~(3)\implies (4).$

**Theorem $1.$** Let $X, ~Y$ be random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P}) .$ Then $$ \mu_X\equiv \mu_Y \iff \mathrm F_X(x) =\mathrm F_Y(x) ~~\forall x\in \mathbb R. \tag 5$$

**Proof.** $(\Leftarrow) $ Use Observation $2.$

$(\Rightarrow) $ Take the sets $(-\infty, x].$

As for whether it is true for $x\in \mathbb Q, $ check whether $\mathcal P^\prime := \{(-\infty,x]: x\in \mathbb Q\}$ is a $\pi$-system and whether or not $\sigma(\mathcal P^\prime) =\mathcal B. $ Check if it is possible to use the same approach above or not.

---

### Reference:

$[\rm I]$ A Probability Path, *Sidney I. Resnick*, Birkhäuser, $1999$; chapter $2, $  pp. $37-38.$

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should also be the case where x is rational since the rationals form a topological space, but I'm not 100% sure here.